# How to create an admin account on Visual Studio Team Services if only admin account has been deleted

Tags: azure-devops

we have created a project and a team on visualstudio.com with one admin and two basic users. Now admin has left the team and we are not able to managing users, because all of us are only basic users. Is there any way to restore his account or change privileges to one of the existing accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to even try to accomplish this is through Support. If the VSTS is AAD managed, they can fix this for you. If the account is Microsoft Account backed, then it is owned by the user and support will likely tell you to create a new account instead. They can't "steal" an account for you.

See:

- https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/team-services/support/